# I can't run `dryscrape` in linux, pythoneverywhere

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, dryscrape

I've successfuly instaled the `dryscrape` along with some accompaning packages (`webkit-server` `xvfbwrapper`) in pythoneverywhere.com.

```
13:45 / $ pip3.5 install --user dryscrape
Collecting dryscrape
  Using cached dryscrape-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting webkit_server>=1.0 (from dryscrape)
  Using cached webkit-server-1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from dryscrape)
Collecting xvfbwrapper (from dryscrape)
  Using cached xvfbwrapper-0.2.8.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dryscrape, webkit-server, xvfbwrapper
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dryscrape ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/igorsavinkin/.cache/pip/wheels/f2/76/aa/8e6b197ff296ec63ac7677880040011f05114eb7a76334ef66
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for webkit-server ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/igorsavinkin/.cache/pip/wheels/a1/d5/20/88fcbe54d8c712563f2a7bd0a57a0743743210ee6d9b724d62
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for xvfbwrapper ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/igorsavinkin/.cache/pip/wheels/5e/03/bc/8fe7ce36b7a38c20d40e49b4f1b46a7e0f2a164ba36f1ed4f6
Successfully built dryscrape webkit-server xvfbwrapper
Installing collected packages: webkit-server, xvfbwrapper, dryscrape
Successfully installed dryscrape webkit-server xvfbwrapper
```

Yet, still I can't run it with session:

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sess = dryscrape.session.Session()
```

Returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/igorsavinkin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 420, in __init__
    self._port = int(re.search(b"port: (\d+)", output).group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/igorsavinkin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dryscrape/session.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.driver = driver or DefaultDriver()
  File "/home/igorsavinkin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dryscrape/driver/webkit.py", line 30, in __init__
    super(Driver, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/home/igorsavinkin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 230, in __init__
    self.conn = connection or ServerConnection()
  File "/home/igorsavinkin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 507, in __init__
    self._sock = (server or get_default_server()).connect()
  File "/home/igorsavinkin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 450, in get_default_server
    _default_server = Server()
  File "/home/igorsavinkin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 427, in __init__
    raise WebkitServerError("webkit-server failed to start. Output:\n" + err)
webkit_server.WebkitServerError: webkit-server failed to start. Output:
webkit_server: cannot connect to X server
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
dryscrape.start_xvfb #then create session
```

Or:

```
import xvfbwrapper as x
x.Xvfb().start()
```

Comment: Please explain what is the issue with OPs approach and how you solved it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have X11 installed which is a windowing system.

http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc.html#webkit_server.NoX11Error

Comment: @Solvit, thank you. as I try to `pip3.5 install --user X11
Collecting X11'` I get *Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement X11 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for X11* error. What's wrong?

Comment: That means you're probably running a version of linux that doesn't support X11 (out of the box, at least).

Comment: is there a way out? I can't change pythoneverywhere.com linux version, can't I?

Comment: Also in [the usage example](http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) the `dryscrape.start_xvfb()` is used. Should I install `xvfb` too?

Comment: I don't know. Is it part of the requirements.txt file that ships with dryscrape?